# Debygawd Cap-en! Where does this phrase come from?

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms, phrase-origin, dialects

I sought out this site because I need help finding the origins of a word/phrase that my family uses. We are from Southern Maryland, USA. The exclamation in question is 'debygawd.' I do not know how to spell it. I cannot find any version of it on the internet. My mother has provided a sample definition;

Debygawd (pronounced Dee-by-gaud)- word that provides emphasis to any declarative sentence. Usually followed by "captain" but pronounced "cap-en." Used in a sentence - "Debygawd cap-en them crabs is runnin today! Picked up a bushel and a half in the first 30 minutes.'

We are from the Potomac River/Chesapeake Bay area. I would say old maryland families, generally 'waterbillies' use this term. Tangier Island and Smith Island both come to mind as potential originators.

Comment: (Something) by God

Comment: Makes me think of _ee ba gum_, a predominantly Yorkshire interjection. The _ee_ has little meaning, like _Ay_ in 'Ay, there's the rub'.

Comment: A search for `"dee by god"` (with the quotes) yielded a [blog post](https://kayakingsouthernmaryland.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/dee-by-god-captn/).

Comment: Maybe 'There by God, Captain'?

Comment: What @Andrew said: [I’ve gone my whole life in Southern Maryland hearing the acclamation: “Dee by gawd, cap’m!” The phrase appears to be a unique part of Chesapeake waterman culture, as far as I can tell, and it supposedly means: “**Indeed, by God, captain**.”](https://kayakingsouthernmaryland.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/dee-by-god-captn/)

Comment: @marcellothearcane 'Ay' means 'yes'. I suppose 'ee' is just a variant of 'eh'.

Comment: @Kate sounds good. Without research I wouldn't know for certain.

Comment: @FumbleFingers an answer!

Comment: @marcellothearcane _Degawd_ is a decade… how would _debygawd_ work to mean two decades? Wouldn’t that just be _dwy ddegawd_ (or _dau ddegawd_ – GPC says it’s both masculine and feminine, not sure what the difference is)?

Comment: @Janus - No idea, it's jusr what came up when I googled it. I bow to your superior Welsh `:)`

Answer (score 4):

It appears 'calls' to God and variations of by God have geen in the English language for centuries:

**pur DEE BY God** in [Shakespeare](https://books.google.com/books?id=BRGBAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA318&dq=%22dee%20by%20god%22%20phrase&pg=PA318#v=onepage&q=%22dee%20by%20god%22%20phrase&f=false)

and

**pardie**, int. (and adv.) and **perdie** and **pardi** and **pardee**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/137768?redirectedFrom=pardy#eid)

> - Now archaic and rare.
> - ‘**By God**!’ (as an asseveration). Hence: ‘certainly!’, ‘without a    doubt!’, ‘**indeed!**’ Also occasionally as adv.

As in:

- > 1387 Chaucer Canterbury Tales    Wel koude he stelen corn and tollen
  >   thries, And yet he hadde a thombe of gold, pardee.

> 1905   A. C. Swinburne Poems III. 134   For all my subtle wiles,
>   perdie, God wot I loved him well enow.

- > 1930   R. Kipling Miracle of St. Jubanus 7   He was of exemplary
  >   life. Pardi, he had to be!

The reference found by other members: **[Indeed, By God](https://kayakingsouthernmaryland.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/dee-by-god-captn/)** appears to be a variation of the same plea/citation to a deity and is specific to the OP's question.